# SwiftUI Drag & Drop - Files from other application

Tags: macos, swiftui

I am using the Drag & Drop feature in macOS SwiftUI application. I have asked a question about the implementation about that feature [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60831260/swiftui-drag-and-drop-files). That answer helped a lot and I am now using the following code.

```
content
    .onDrop(of: ["public.file-url"], isTargeted: true, perform: { providers -> Bool in
        for provider in providers
        {
            provider.loadDataRepresentation(forTypeIdentifier: "public.file-url", completionHandler: { (data, error) in
                if let data = data, let path = NSString(data: data, encoding: 4), let url = URL(string: path as String) {
```

It works fine, however I want to extend to be able to drag and drop files from other applications into mine. For example: Dragging a mail file from the Apple Mail application into mine or vCard File from Adress book. That won't work at the moment. How can I extend my code to allow drag and drop for these kind of files.

I think I have to modify the `of` parameter `["public.file-url"]`, however I couldn't figure it out.

Comment: Does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/a/64727841/12299030?

Comment: Also refer this https://stackoverflow.com/a/64738417/12299030, but as I recall there is not file there.

Comment: @Asperi Thanks! The first one looks promising. Will try it out, didn't find that one, my bad